# uglifyjs mangle props ".source" error

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I have some problems using UglifyJS.
When i am using uglifyjs with this command:
`uglifyjs -o live_ugly.js --compress --mangle-props 1 --mangle -r "$,require,exports" live.js`

I gives me an error : `Cannot read property 'source' of undefined`

The code for this line is : `new RegExp(this.Qd.source + "|" + /\d{1,2}/.source)`

The code before uglify is : `new RegExp(this._ordinalParse.source+"|"+/\d{1,2}/.source`

I have ReactJS code in it too. The source code i am trying to mangle went through webpack before.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `new RegExp(this.Qd.source + "|" + /\d{1,2}/.source)` from which file?

Comment: I just added a comment, it from 'new RegExp(this._ordinalParse.source+"|"+/\d{1,2}/.source' , i think it's from moment.js

Comment: My question is that `new RegExp(this._ordinalParse.source+"|"+/\d{1,2}/.source` is in `live_ugly.js` file?

Comment: No, it's in the original file -> live.js. new RegExp(this.Qd.source + "|" + /\d{1,2}/.source) is the output of uglifyjs

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding the `compress` parameter to UglifyJsPlugin